# Inline Edit Not Working In Admin Grid Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, grid, edit, inline-editor

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

        <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">freelayoutindex.freelayout_alllayout_listing_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">freelayoutindex.freelayout_alllayout_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">allnews_columns</item>

         </argument>
        <dataSource name="freelayout_alllayout_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">AlllayoutGridDataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">freelayout_alllayout_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
     <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
     <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
     </item>
     </item>
     </argument>
     </argument>
     </dataSource>
     <listingToolbar name="listing_top">

    <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
    <columnsControls name="columns_controls" />
    <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
    <filters name="listing_filters">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <templates>
                <filters>
                    <select>
                        <param name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</param>
                        <param name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</param>
                    </select>
                </filters>
            </templates>
        </settings>
    </filters>

    <paging name="listing_paging"/>
</listingToolbar>
<columns name="allnews_columns">
     <settings>
        <editorConfig>
            <param name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="freelayout/Index/inlineEdit"/>
                <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </param>
            <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</param>
            <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
            <param name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">freelayoutindex.freelayoutindex.alllayout_columns.ids</param>
        </editorConfig>
        <childDefaults>
            <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">freelayoutindex.freelayoutindex.allnews_columns_editor</item>
                <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                    <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </param>
        </childDefaults>
    </settings>
    <column name="id">
        <settings>
            <filter>textRange</filter>
            <label translate="true">ID</label>
            <sorting>asc</sorting>
        </settings>
    </column>

    <column name="name">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <editor>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <editorType>text</editorType>
            </editor>
            <label translate="true">Name</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="name">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <editor>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <editorType>text</editorType>
            </editor>
            <label translate="true">Name</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="entity_id" class="Magneto\BookFreeLayout\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Products">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <editor>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <editorType>text</editorType>
            </editor>
            <label translate="true">Sku</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
   <column name="status" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
        <settings>
            <options class="Magneto\BookFreeLayout\Model\Alllayout\Source\Status"/>
            <filter>select</filter>
            <editor>
                <editorType>select</editorType>
            </editor>
            <dataType>select</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Status</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
</columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

your provider is not okay, you have:

freelayoutindex.freelayoutindex.alllayout_columns.ids

and it must be:

freelayoutindex.freelayoutindex.alllayout_allnews_columns

The ".ids" is the name os the selectionsColums field but you dont have it implemented so i think it will work like that.